# How to return week number + year + friday number of week

Tags: postgresql

In sql it looks like this:

```
select to_char(d,'WW')    as Week
     , to_char(d,'YYYY')  as Year
     , to_char(d,'DD')    as "Day of Friday"
     , d
from (
      select (level-1)*7 + to_date('02/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') d
        from dual
      connect by level <= 53*5);
```

but i need a Postgres script...

Comment: Everything you need to write the script is in the [PostgreSQL Date functions reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies

This is what i wanted:

```
SELECT 
     extract('week' from d) as "Week"
    ,extract('year' from d) as "Year"
    ,extract('day' from d)  as "Friday Number"
FROM generate_series('2015-01-02'::date, '2015-12-31'::date, '1 week'::interval) d
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `extract(year from <your date field>)` ? Look at [date-time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

Postgres date time masks are almost same. In you case I guess they are equal:

```
select to_char(d,'WW')    as Week
     , to_char(d,'YYYY')  as Year
     , to_char(d,'DD')    as "Day of Friday"
     , d
from to_date('02/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') d
```

gives:

> 01;2015;12;2015-01-12

unless Week not expected to be first and "Day of Friday" is not a day of a month...